# Method in Angular 2 is either undefined or not callable

Tags: angular

I am working on a personal Angular project. Still trying to learn and move from AngularJS to Angular :)

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _loginService: LoginService
    ) {
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if ( token ) {
                this._loginService.isLoggedIn(token)
                    .subscribe(v => {
                        return v.status == 'ok';
                    });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };

    canActivate() {
        console.log(this.isLoggedIn());

        if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        };
    }

}
```

However my problem is:

1. If I keep `this.` on the `console.log(this.isLoggedIn());` then "undefined" is printed out.
2. If I remove it, then I have the following message on VS Code `[ts] Cannot find name 'isLoggedIn'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.isLoggedIn'?` and the same on console `Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: isLoggedIn is not defined`
3. The method `isLoggedIn()` is used without a problem from other files where I call it.

Comment: Are you logged in when undefined is printed? Can you try executing the code when you are logged out? I think you are calling everything correctly but the `isLoggedIn` method does not return a value in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting undefined on the method:

```
isLoggedIn() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if ( token ) {
        this._loginService.isLoggedIn(token)
              .subscribe(v => {
                   return v.status == 'ok';
         });
     } else {
           return false;
      }
};
```

Is because the Subscription `this._loginService.isLoggedIn(token)` is asynchronous and does not return immediately.  So the method `isLoggedIn()` finishes executing and returns before there is a response.

What you could do instead and what I do is the have your `_loginService` maintain a local variable that other components can read and consume or a function that can synchronously check the token to make sure it's valid.  If a token exists, then a user has logged in, and what you can do from there is check the token to make sure it hasn't expired.  That could be done a couple different ways.  If your using the `angular2-jwt` library to help handle your JWT token you could have a method in your `_loginService` that looks something like this:

```
authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    return tokenNotExpired();
}
```

If you aren't using the `angular-jwt` library to help manage the JWT token, you could do something like this:

```
isTokenValid(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let decodedToken = window.atob(token.split('.')[1]);

    if((decodedToken.exp * 1000) < Date.now()){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I don't user `angular2-jwt`, I want to test the `isTokenValid()` method. However, I am not sure what is between the `decoded` and the `decodedToken` lines. Are those the same and just a typo or somehow you get the decodedToken from the first one?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: I found that I need to split the token at "." and take the second instance. But after that everything was ok. Will mark your answer as best but please edit it with the last update. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

This may not qualify as an answer but I do not have enough reputation points to post a comment - so everyone, pardon me :)

I think you cannot return a value from subscribe like that as it is an async call..

Instead, your isLoggedIn() method should be returned as shown below:

```
isLoggedIn() {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if ( token ) {
                return this._loginService.isLoggedIn(token)
                    .subscribe(v => {
                        return v.status == 'ok';
                    });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Note the change is here: `return this._loginService.isLoggedIn(token)...` Hope this helps.

EDIT: 
Ignore my answer above... That would still not work :( sorry... 
What's happening is, you are calling isLoggedIn() which executes an asynchronous call (ie a call that will continue executing in the background and return later). That is why you are getting an 'undefined'. What I would do is follow Tyler's advice above and have a local variable in which you store the returned value in and utilize later OR you could pass in a callback to isLoggedIn() method - this callback will be invoked once the async call is done. See below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _loginService: LoginService
    ) {
    }

    isLoggedIn(callback: (v) => void) {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            if ( token ) {
                this._loginService.isLoggedIn(token)
                    .subscribe(v => {
                        callback(v)
                    });
            }
        };

    canActivate() {
        this.isLoggedIn((v) => { // this here is your callback function which will get invoked once async call is done
            if(v.status == 'ok' {
                // do something... 
                return true;
            } else {
               // do something 
               this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        });
    }

}
```